# Nested List<List<string>> XAML output to ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, observablecollection

I'm hoping someone has had a similar issue to me and can help me out!

I am trying to bind an `ObservableCollection<List<string>>` to a `ListView` but I'm having issues formatting the output.

Here is the nested structure:

**C#**

```
 //Setting variables
 private ObservableCollection<List<string>> _results;
 public ObservableCollection<List<string>> Results
 {
      get => _results;
      set { _results = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Results)); }
 }

 //Initialise variables
 private async Task<bool> runAsync() {
      List<List<string>> targets = new List<List<string>>();
      targets = await Task.FromResult(dataConverter.getFromFile());

      Results = new ObservableCollection<List<string>>(targets);
      foreach (var target in targets)
       {
           List<string> new_result = new List<string>();
           foreach (var element in target)
           {
               new_result.Add(element);
           }

           Results.Add(new_result);
       }
       return true;
}
```

Basically, `dataConverter.getFromFile()` will read from a CSV a string of information, and then read it into a `List<List<string>>`. I **know** this section works as I've been manually concatenating the data & printing it to a label on the front-end.

**XAML**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**The Output**

It puts each element on a new "row", whereas I want each `List<string>` as a series of "columns".

So.. In essense:

- There is a `List<List<string>>`
- Each `string` inside `List<string>` should be a new column with the data inside
- Each `List<List<string>>` should be a new row

Like so:

[image]

**Example data:**

- A `List<string>` entry could equal: { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" }
- A `Results` is of the format `List<List<string>>` and would be a collection of these `List<string>` entries.

Not sure why I'm having so much trouble with this - but if anyone has the solution - it would be appreciated!

Please feel free to ask questions & sorry for the essay. :)

Comment: Have you tried to move `List<string>` into the separate class, representing an item in `ObservableCollection`? I'm not sure, that you can use `List<List<string>>` and `List<string>` in binding properly, because `List` doesn't support INPC

Comment: Could you give me a full example of what you're suggesting?